# How do I check if my build.xml works?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using Java to create android applications and I just created a build.xml by updating my project, now I want to test to see if it works, how do I do that?

This is the instructions to run it:

You can now use this file by executing "ant debug", or "ant" to see all options.
You can test that it work in eclipse by executing the new "build.xml" file in your project 
directory (as ant file, use debug as the target, or even debug install)

but I dont understand them

Comment: Just run the `build.xml`???

Comment: how? do I run that in eclipse????

Comment: Right click on build.xml and chose Run as ANT build :)

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command via cmd / command line console:

```
ant debug -f {path_to_your_build.xml}
```